# $(this).find(..) alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I find my self doing this but not sure if this is the best way. Here an example.

```
<ul id="menubar">
  <li><a class="menu_item">File</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="menu_file_new">New</a></li>
      <li><a id="menu_file_open">Open</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="menu_item">Run</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="menu_run_preview">Preview</a></li>
      <li><a id="menu_run_compile">Compile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
$('.menu_item').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});
```

Just wondering is this the best way, find seems a bit overkill?

---

**EDIT: I can't use css because of this: Fails in Opera/IE when an item is clicked/hover it fails in those two browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/cJsn2/1/ this is because of html standard.**

Comment: I believe you can also use `$('ul', this).show()`

Comment: I would think you would really want: `$(this).find('>ul').show();` in case you want to do multiple levels in the future. Also remember that not everyone uses a mouse. Pick a menu library from the net that does all of the hard work for you.

Comment: @CaseyFoster, it would work, but it is slower.

Comment: `$('#menubar, #menubar ul).attr('display','block');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a simple hover script:

```
// I'm purposely using `toggleClass`, instead of show/hide, to
// have more flexibility with styling
$('.menu_item').each(function () {
  var $li = $(this).closest('li');

  $(this).hover(function () {
    $li.toggleClass('hover');
  });
});
```

with the following css:

```
ul ul {
  display: none;
}

li.hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ehifod/1/

Comment: this is fine but I was planning to use .hover(func(),func()) one for  mouseover and one for mouseout ? Is this bad? Hover seems to support that? Maybe your method above is better but a bit too complex.

Comment: @CezarisLT I don't think it makes much of a difference, either hover with two functions (one to add, one to remove a class), or only one function (using `toggleClass`) is essentially the same. I think the added complexity of my example comes from the fact, that I like to *cache* my selectors. E.g. only executing `$(this).closest('li');` once for each `.menu_item` instead of constantly evaluting it inside the hover-callback.

Comment: and this i'm amusing yields performance? Can you quickly explain how?

Comment: Well, jQuery will only look for the closest `li` once per `.menu_item`. Without caching it, it would look every time a mouseover/mouseout happens.

Comment: [Here](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) is a helpful article about the topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS only

```
.menu_item ul { display: none; }
.menu_item:hover ul {display: block; }
```

as for the JavaScript, it's fine, you can use $.children instead of $.find to traverse less nodes

Comment: That fine but I ran into a problem with css and Opera/IE with menubars that unfixable because of lack of support.

Comment: @CezarisLT im sure there are many shims or shivs to update support.

Comment: From the given html, there is no `ul` *in* an `a`-tag. (nor should it)

Comment: I can't use css because of this: Fails in Opera/IE when an item is clicked/hover it fails in those two browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/cJsn2/1/ this is because of html standard.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). It travels up the DOM-tree to find the first parent element matching the selector:

```
$('.menu_item').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').show();
});
```

```
$(".menu_item").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this with just css

the catch is that you're going to apply the "hover" on the  *li*  and not in the  *a*

```
#menubar li ul{ 
  display:none; 
}

#menubar li:hover > ul{ 
  display:block; 
}
```

[jsfiddle >](http://jsfiddle.net/xpwUa/)

Comment: I can't use css because of this: Fails in Opera/IE when an item is clicked/hover it fails in those two browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/cJsn2/1/ this is because of html standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS (this is under the assumption that the `ul` element is contained within the `.menu_item` element):

```
.menu_item:hover > ul {
   display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/cJsn2/

Using the following HTML:

```
<ul id="menubar">
  <li class="menu_item"><a>File</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="menu_file_new">New</a></li>
      <li><a id="menu_file_open">Open</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a>Run</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="menu_run_preview">Preview</a></li>
      <li><a id="menu_run_compile">Compile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```